# How to search for patterns in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with entries like

- ABC001
- ABC1
- ABC100D
- BCD1
- ABC2
- ABC020
- ABC201
- CED12

and so on.
I want to query for all entries, that are like the entries in my search-List. Leading Zeros are optional

- ABC1, ABC01 and ABC001 are the same
- ABC010 is different to the items above
- Items without number find all items, that start with that number
- it is allowed to combine searches: ABC1, BCD, ZXD

I first had an approach with

```
select * from table t where t.itemname in 'ABC1', 'BCD', 'ZXD'
```

but I need another approach.. any best practices or suggestions?
I am using Java with JPA Criteria API for the Implementation, but that's not that important.

My next try would be, to change from in to an "and / or" concatination, where I search with likes on pre 'calculated' values. 
so, in Java I would create a List of Search-Terms: "ABC1" becomes "ABC%1", BCD becomes "BCD%" and so on. and then I query

```
select * from table t 
  where t.itemname like 'ABC%1' 
  or t.itemname like 'BCD%'
  or t.itemname like,'ZXD%'
```

is there a better way?

Comment: And the database is...?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? support for pattern matching that goes beyond a simple LIKE is very different for each database vendor

Answer (score 1):

In SQL regular expressions are called pattern matching, and the `LIKE` operator acts much like a `match` function in a scripting regular expression:

I **THINK** you could try some variation of the following:

`select * from table t 
  where t.itemname like '%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][^0][0-9]%'`

Comment: Here's some documentation on the `LIKE` operator for pattern matching: [LIKE Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: LIKE does not support regular expressions in (standard) SQL